# Unable to connect browser to any of my docker images

Tags: django, docker

I downloaded cookiecutter django to start a new project the other day. I spun it up (along with postgres, redis, etc) inside docker containers. The configuration files should be fine because they were all generated by coockicutter.

However, once I build and turn on the containers I am unable to see the "hello world" splash page when I connect to my localhost:8000. But there is something going wrong between the applications and the containers because I am able to connect to them via telnet and through docker exec -it commands etc. The only thing I can think of is some sort of permissions issue? So I gave all the files/directors 777 permissions to test that but that hasnt changed anything.

logs

```
 % docker compose -f local.yml up
[+] Running 8/0
 ⠿ Container dashboard_local_docs          Created                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 ⠿ Container dashboard_local_redis         Created                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 ⠿ Container dashboard_local_mailhog       Created                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 ⠿ Container dashboard_local_postgres      Created                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 ⠿ Container dashboard_local_django        Created                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 ⠿ Container dashboard_local_celeryworker  Created                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 ⠿ Container dashboard_local_celerybeat    Created                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 ⠿ Container dashboard_local_flower        Created                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
Attaching to dashboard_local_celerybeat, dashboard_local_celeryworker, dashboard_local_django, dashboard_local_docs, dashboard_local_flower, dashboard_local_mailhog, dashboard_local_postgres, dashboard_local_redis
dashboard_local_postgres      | 
dashboard_local_postgres      | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
dashboard_local_postgres      | 
dashboard_local_postgres      | 2022-07-07 14:36:15.969 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.4 (Debian 14.4-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
dashboard_local_postgres      | 2022-07-07 14:36:15.992 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
dashboard_local_postgres      | 2022-07-07 14:36:15.992 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
dashboard_local_postgres      | 2022-07-07 14:36:15.995 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
dashboard_local_postgres      | 2022-07-07 14:36:15.999 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-07-07 14:35:47 UTC
dashboard_local_postgres      | 2022-07-07 14:36:16.004 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
dashboard_local_mailhog       | 2022/07/07 14:36:16 Using in-memory storage
dashboard_local_mailhog       | 2022/07/07 14:36:16 [SMTP] Binding to address: 0.0.0.0:1025
dashboard_local_mailhog       | 2022/07/07 14:36:16 Serving under http://0.0.0.0:8025/
dashboard_local_mailhog       | [HTTP] Binding to address: 0.0.0.0:8025
dashboard_local_mailhog       | Creating API v1 with WebPath: 
dashboard_local_mailhog       | Creating API v2 with WebPath: 
dashboard_local_docs          | sphinx-autobuild -b html --host 0.0.0.0 --port 9000 --watch /app -c . . ./_build/html
dashboard_local_docs          | [sphinx-autobuild] > sphinx-build -b html -c . /docs /docs/_build/html
dashboard_local_redis         | 1:C 07 Jul 2022 14:36:17.057 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
dashboard_local_redis         | 1:C 07 Jul 2022 14:36:17.057 # Redis version=6.2.7, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
dashboard_local_redis         | 1:C 07 Jul 2022 14:36:17.057 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
dashboard_local_redis         | 1:M 07 Jul 2022 14:36:17.057 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
dashboard_local_redis         | 1:M 07 Jul 2022 14:36:17.057 # A key '__redis__compare_helper' was added to Lua globals which is not on the globals allow list nor listed on the deny list.
dashboard_local_redis         | 1:M 07 Jul 2022 14:36:17.057 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
dashboard_local_redis         | 1:M 07 Jul 2022 14:36:17.057 # Server initialized
dashboard_local_redis         | 1:M 07 Jul 2022 14:36:17.057 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
dashboard_local_redis         | 1:M 07 Jul 2022 14:36:17.058 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.2.7
dashboard_local_redis         | 1:M 07 Jul 2022 14:36:17.058 * RDB age 30 seconds
dashboard_local_redis         | 1:M 07 Jul 2022 14:36:17.058 * RDB memory usage when created 0.78 Mb
dashboard_local_redis         | 1:M 07 Jul 2022 14:36:17.058 # Done loading RDB, keys loaded: 3, keys expired: 0.
dashboard_local_redis         | 1:M 07 Jul 2022 14:36:17.058 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
dashboard_local_redis         | 1:M 07 Jul 2022 14:36:17.058 * Ready to accept connections
dashboard_local_docs          | Running Sphinx v5.0.1
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | PostgreSQL is available
dashboard_local_celerybeat    | PostgreSQL is available
dashboard_local_docs          | loading pickled environment... done
dashboard_local_docs          | building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
dashboard_local_docs          | building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
dashboard_local_docs          | updating environment: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
dashboard_local_docs          | looking for now-outdated files... none found
dashboard_local_docs          | no targets are out of date.
dashboard_local_docs          | build succeeded.
dashboard_local_docs          | 
dashboard_local_docs          | The HTML pages are in _build/html.
dashboard_local_docs          | [I 220707 14:36:18 server:335] Serving on http://0.0.0.0:9000
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | [14:36:18] watching "/app" and reloading "celery.__main__.main" on changes...
dashboard_local_docs          | [I 220707 14:36:18 handlers:62] Start watching changes
dashboard_local_docs          | [I 220707 14:36:18 handlers:64] Start detecting changes
dashboard_local_django        | PostgreSQL is available
dashboard_local_celerybeat    | celery beat v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus) is starting.
dashboard_local_flower        | PostgreSQL is available
dashboard_local_celerybeat    | __    -    ... __   -        _
dashboard_local_celerybeat    | LocalTime -> 2022-07-07 09:36:19
dashboard_local_celerybeat    | Configuration ->
dashboard_local_celerybeat    |     . broker -> redis://redis:6379/0
dashboard_local_celerybeat    |     . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
dashboard_local_celerybeat    |     . scheduler -> django_celery_beat.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler
dashboard_local_celerybeat    | 
dashboard_local_celerybeat    |     . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
dashboard_local_celerybeat    |     . maxinterval -> 5.00 seconds (5s)
dashboard_local_celerybeat    | [2022-07-07 09:36:19,658: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/platforms.py:840: SecurityWarning: You're running the worker with superuser privileges: this is
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | absolutely not recommended!
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | 
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | Please specify a different user using the --uid option.
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | 
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | 
dashboard_local_celeryworker  |   warnings.warn(SecurityWarning(ROOT_DISCOURAGED.format(
dashboard_local_celeryworker  |  
dashboard_local_celeryworker  |  -------------- celery@e1ac9f770cbd v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | --- ***** ----- 
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | -- ******* ---- Linux-5.4.0-96-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.31 2022-07-07 09:36:19
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | - *** --- * --- 
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | - ** ---------- [config]
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | - ** ---------- .> app:         dashboard:0x7fd9dcaeb1c0
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | - ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://redis:6379/0
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | - ** ---------- .> results:     redis://redis:6379/0
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | --- ***** ----- 
dashboard_local_celeryworker  |  -------------- [queues]
dashboard_local_celeryworker  |                 .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
dashboard_local_celeryworker  |                 
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | 
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | [tasks]
dashboard_local_celeryworker  |   . dashboard.users.tasks.get_users_count
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | 
dashboard_local_django        | Operations to perform:
dashboard_local_django        |   Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, django_celery_beat, sessions, sites, socialaccount, users
dashboard_local_django        | Running migrations:
dashboard_local_django        |   No migrations to apply.
dashboard_local_flower        | INFO 2022-07-07 09:36:20,646 command 7 140098896897856 Visit me at http://localhost:5555
dashboard_local_flower        | INFO 2022-07-07 09:36:20,652 command 7 140098896897856 Broker: redis://redis:6379/0
dashboard_local_flower        | INFO 2022-07-07 09:36:20,655 command 7 140098896897856 Registered tasks: 
dashboard_local_flower        | ['celery.accumulate',
dashboard_local_flower        |  'celery.backend_cleanup',
dashboard_local_flower        |  'celery.chain',
dashboard_local_flower        |  'celery.chord',
dashboard_local_flower        |  'celery.chord_unlock',
dashboard_local_flower        |  'celery.chunks',
dashboard_local_flower        |  'celery.group',
dashboard_local_flower        |  'celery.map',
dashboard_local_flower        |  'celery.starmap',
dashboard_local_flower        |  'dashboard.users.tasks.get_users_count']
dashboard_local_flower        | INFO 2022-07-07 09:36:20,663 mixins 7 140098817644288 Connected to redis://redis:6379/0
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | [2022-07-07 09:36:20,792: INFO/SpawnProcess-1] Connected to redis://redis:6379/0
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | [2022-07-07 09:36:20,794: INFO/SpawnProcess-1] mingle: searching for neighbors
dashboard_local_flower        | WARNING 2022-07-07 09:36:21,700 inspector 7 140098800826112 Inspect method active_queues failed
dashboard_local_flower        | WARNING 2022-07-07 09:36:21,710 inspector 7 140098766993152 Inspect method reserved failed
dashboard_local_flower        | WARNING 2022-07-07 09:36:21,712 inspector 7 140098784040704 Inspect method scheduled failed
dashboard_local_flower        | WARNING 2022-07-07 09:36:21,714 inspector 7 140098758600448 Inspect method revoked failed
dashboard_local_flower        | WARNING 2022-07-07 09:36:21,715 inspector 7 140098792433408 Inspect method registered failed
dashboard_local_flower        | WARNING 2022-07-07 09:36:21,715 inspector 7 140098276423424 Inspect method conf failed
dashboard_local_flower        | WARNING 2022-07-07 09:36:21,715 inspector 7 140098809218816 Inspect method stats failed
dashboard_local_flower        | WARNING 2022-07-07 09:36:21,716 inspector 7 140098775648000 Inspect method active failed
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | [2022-07-07 09:36:21,802: INFO/SpawnProcess-1] mingle: all alone
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | [2022-07-07 09:36:21,811: WARNING/SpawnProcess-1] /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:203: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
dashboard_local_celeryworker  |             leak, never use this setting in production environments!
dashboard_local_celeryworker  |   warnings.warn('''Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | 
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | [2022-07-07 09:36:21,811: INFO/SpawnProcess-1] celery@e1ac9f770cbd ready.
dashboard_local_django        | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
dashboard_local_django        | INFO 2022-07-07 09:36:22,862 autoreload 9 140631340287808 Watching for file changes with StatReloader
dashboard_local_django        | Performing system checks...
dashboard_local_django        | 
dashboard_local_django        | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
dashboard_local_django        | July 07, 2022 - 09:36:23
dashboard_local_django        | Django version 3.2.14, using settings 'config.settings.local'
dashboard_local_django        | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
dashboard_local_django        | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
dashboard_local_celeryworker  | [2022-07-07 09:36:25,661: INFO/SpawnProcess-1] Events of group {task} enabled by remote.
```

docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS         PORTS                                                 NAMES
69591187e44d   dashboard_local_flower          "/entrypoint /start-…"   11 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:5555->5555/tcp, :::5555->5555/tcp             dashboard_local_flower
15914b6b91e0   dashboard_local_celerybeat      "/entrypoint /start-…"   11 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes                                                         dashboard_local_celerybeat
e1ac9f770cbd   dashboard_local_celeryworker    "/entrypoint /start-…"   11 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes                                                         dashboard_local_celeryworker
6bbfc900c346   dashboard_local_django          "/entrypoint /start"     11 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp             dashboard_local_django
b8bec3422bae   redis:6                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   6379/tcp                                              dashboard_local_redis
2b7c3d9eabe3   dashboard_production_postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   5432/tcp                                              dashboard_local_postgres
0249aaaa040c   mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.0          "MailHog"                11 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   1025/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8025->8025/tcp, :::8025->8025/tcp   dashboard_local_mailhog
d5dd94cbb070   dashboard_local_docs            "/start-docs"            11 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, :::9000->9000/tcp             dashboard_local_docs
```

the ports are listening

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]

% sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29532/smbd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43979         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31867/BlastServer   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      963/rpcbind         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46641           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:51857           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4149/rpc.statd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5555            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14326/docker-proxy  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6100            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31908/Xorg          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      973/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29295/sshd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8025            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13769/docker-proxy  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30117/master        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      882/sshd: noakes@no 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29532/smbd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14272/docker-proxy  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13850/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      29532/smbd          
tcp6       0      0 :::40717                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::41423                :::*                    LISTEN      4149/rpc.statd      
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      963/rpcbind         
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:41265         :::*                    LISTEN      30056/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::5555                 :::*                    LISTEN      14333/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::6100                 :::*                    LISTEN      31908/Xorg          
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      29295/sshd          
tcp6       0      0 :::13782                :::*                    LISTEN      2201/xinetd         
tcp6       0      0 :::13783                :::*                    LISTEN      2201/xinetd         
tcp6       0      0 :::8025                 :::*                    LISTEN      13779/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      30117/master        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN      882/sshd: noakes@no 
tcp6       0      0 :::13722                :::*                    LISTEN      2201/xinetd         
tcp6       0      0 :::6556                 :::*                    LISTEN      2201/xinetd         
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      29532/smbd          
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      14278/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::1057                 :::*                    LISTEN      2201/xinetd         
tcp6       0      0 :::7778                 :::*                    LISTEN      2201/xinetd         
tcp6       0      0 :::7779                 :::*                    LISTEN      2201/xinetd         
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      13860/docker-proxy
```

local.yml

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  dashboard_local_postgres_data: {}
  dashboard_local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django: &django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
      #user: "root:root"
    image: dashboard_local_django
    container_name: dashboard_local_django
    platform: linux/x86_64
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
      - mailhog
    volumes:
      - .:/app:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: dashboard_production_postgres
    container_name: dashboard_local_postgres
    volumes:
      - dashboard_local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
      - dashboard_local_postgres_data_backups:/backups:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres

  docs:
    image: dashboard_local_docs
    container_name: dashboard_local_docs
    platform: linux/x86_64
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/docs/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
    volumes:
      - ./docs:/docs:z
      - ./config:/app/config:z
      - ./dashboard:/app/dashboard:z
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    command: /start-docs

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.0
    container_name: dashboard_local_mailhog
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"

  redis:
    image: redis:6
    container_name: dashboard_local_redis

  celeryworker:
    <<: *django
    image: dashboard_local_celeryworker
    container_name: dashboard_local_celeryworker
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - mailhog
    ports: []
    command: /start-celeryworker

  celerybeat:
    <<: *django
    image: dashboard_local_celerybeat
    container_name: dashboard_local_celerybeat
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - mailhog
    ports: []
    command: /start-celerybeat

  flower:
    <<: *django
    image: dashboard_local_flower
    container_name: dashboard_local_flower
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    command: /start-flower
```

Comment: What's the more specific problem you're having?  Instead of the diagnostic information, can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] with enough source code to demonstrate the problem?  I can tell you that setting a file or directory with mode 0777 is pretty much always wrong, but it's not obvious what problem you're trying to work around.

Comment: The problem is that the browser is not getting a response. It is hard to know what to include because I am not getting any errors/unusual logging.  I know 777 isn't safe, but I just wanted to test if permissions were an issue. I honestly don't even know where to go from here, it should just work